# Create drop-down product attribute for frontend

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How to create an drop-down product attribute for frontend programmatically .

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link :
https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/

It describes all the steps for achieving what you are looking for .